# What's the difference between "--section=data" and "--data-only" of pg_dump/pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-dump, pg-restore

In the man page of pg_dump/pg_restore, that is mentioned about `--data-only` option(but I didn't find --section=data) as following:

> --data-only
> Dump only the data, not the schema (data definitions). Table data, large objects, and sequence values are dumped.
> **This option is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying --section=data**.

I'm interested in what is the difference between those two.
Thanks!

Comment: The `--section` flag absolutely is documented, keep reading. If you go read the source, you'll see that the differences aren't trivial to enumerate because the two flags are implemented completely differently - see the scattered checks for `dataOnly` all over pg_dump.c, whereas `--section` makes use of [`_teSection`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2a712066d0587f65fcecd44e884dc6a09958dbdd/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup.h#L53) via the ARCHIVE_OPTS macro when defining dumpable objects.

Comment: The practical answer to this is "run both and compare the output to see what the difference is for your data." (If there is any.)

Comment: Is there difference in speed? Looks like the `--section` option is newer but the docs should state the difference between 2 options if they are both so similar (on paper, at least)...